# Swapping values in an array

Tags: javascript

This function should swap the values in the array `A` that are at position `i` and `j`. For example, if `A = [3,2,1,6,4]`
`swap(A, 2,3)` should change `A` so it is now:
`A = [3,2,6,1,4]`
we're swapping the `1` at position `2` and the `6` at position `3` so now the `6` is at position `2` and the `1` is at position `3`.

Problem is, I do not know how to swap these! (New to programming)

```js
function swap(A, i, j) {
  var swap = myArray[j];
  myArray[j] = myArray[i];
  myArray[i] = swap;
}

const A = [3, 2, 1, 6, 4];
console.log(swap(A, 2, 3))
```

Comment: `myArray` should be changed to `A` (eg `var swap = A[j];`). Otherwise looks fine

Comment: `console.log(swap)` should be `console.log(A)`

Answer (score 1):

Just need to pass the array and swapping indexes. You need to get the value at index `i` and `j` using `array index` as `myArray[i]` or `myArray[j]`

```js
function swap(myArray, i, j) {
  var swap = myArray[j];
  myArray[j] = myArray[i];
  myArray[i] = swap;
}

const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
swap(array, 1, 3);
console.log(array)
```

Comment: Actually you can even do without the `swap` variable by using [destructuring](https://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment). You could just write `[arr[i], arr[j]] = [arr[j], arr[i]]` which also makes the code easier to read imho.

Comment: @KrisztiánBalla, Thanks for suggestion. But as the OP is a new programmer so I thought it would be easy for him to grasp the concept he know it already like accessing the array value using `index` ☺

Comment: It is not working for me, it seems there is no output?

Comment: working code is there just `Run code snippet`

Comment: var myArray = [];

this is auto generated from a generation function, I am using this array instead of the one you have given. We're swapping the 1 at position 2 and the 6 at position 3 so now the 6 is at position 2 and the 1 is at position 3.